# Center row items in twitter bootstrapper css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the twitter bootstrapper for this project,

How do I horizontally centralized the items in the page? If you resize the frames, you'll see that the items within row div are not centralized, the skew to left and there is a lot of empty space on the right.

I tried defining a new class centerdiv, but it's not helping

http://jsfiddle.net/VuaYz/6/

Answer (score 0):

use offset css class. Example class="span6 offset2"

Comment: I just tried the fiddle.. I put a span12 on the hero-unit and then span10 offset2 on the row where you had the centerdiv... doesn't look too bad.. you can play with it from thereon now..

Comment: Do you mind updating the jsfiddle so I can see what you've done?